# Is it possible to get name of modified method instead of just the class name with perforce?

Tags: java, parsing, perforce

I was wondering if you have an idea about how retrieve the name of a modified methods instead of the class name in perforce?

I mean, when you want to see the changes you have done before commit it, you type: p4 opened

So know, I want to find the modified line, analyze the java file and say: ok you have modified some code in these methods or ok you have modified something outside any methods (like an attribute)

So my question is: How I should do that? Any libraries can do that? A Parser like JavaCC is a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perforce doesn't provide any kind of custom parsers which could figure out information like that.  The point of change management systems is that they can hold any kind of files.

Which methods changed would be specific to the source (in this case java files) and would be very tricky to implement because every language would require its own parser.

Could it be done?  Maybe, but change management is already tricky enough as it is and I don't see any big change management project coupling themselves to a specific language to accomplish what you're asking for.

In the meantime, you could just use `p4 diff /path/to/file/NameOfFile.java` before you submit.  This will show you which lines changed and in most cases it is sufficient to narrow down what exactly changed.  Before I submit, I usually go through and `p4 diff` every file listed when I run `p4 opened` and `p4 revert` any files I marked for edit, but didn't end up making any changes to.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the P4Eclipse plugin, which offers a Java-aware diff view.